# Secured pdf says signing is allowed, but I can't seem to do it

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

The pdf in question is from the government of Canada. [Here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/td1/td1-fill-16e.pdf) is the a link to the file, and [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/td1/README.html) is the website.

When I open the file in adobe acrobat, I can edit all the forms, but can't add a signature at the bottom (the "sign" option is greyed out. I check the properties of the document, and it says signature is **allowed**. How do I sign it?

I have both Acrobate 11 and Reader 11 installed. I have tried both, but neither will let me sign the document.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

Open the pdf in chrome, print it to pdf. You can now edit it.

Comment: Please define the specific steps you took rather than just and only the basic advise. What if someone else tries to "open" it but it does not open with Chrome for example. Your answer detail for your solution is rather vague when read from a non-technical person's perspective.

Comment: Oh, never thought of this. So secured PDFs are useless actually...